# Show: $\prod_i t_i^{w_it_i} \geq \Big( \frac{\sum_i w_it_i}{\sum_i w_i} \Big)^{\sum_i w_it_i}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $w_i$ be $k$ weights and $t_i$ be k numbers s.t. $w_i , t_i \geq 0$. Then prove that:

\begin{align*}
\prod_i t_i^{w_it_i} \geq \Big( \frac{\sum_i w_it_i}{\sum_i w_i} \Big)^{\sum_i w_it_i}
\end{align*}

**Background:**
Let $J(p,x_1, .. , x_k) := \Bigg( \frac{\sum_{i}w_ix_i^p}{\sum_{i}w_i} \Bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ for $x_i > 0$ and $p \in \mathbb{R}$ be the power means function. Now as $J$ is increasing in $p$, we have $\frac{\partial J}{\partial p} \ge 0$. And,
\begin{align*}
\frac{p^2}{J(p,x_1, .. , x_k)} \cdot \frac{\partial J(p,x_1, .. , x_k)}{\partial p} &= \ln\Bigg( \frac{\prod_i \big(x_i^p \big)^{\frac{w_ix_i^p}{\sum_i w_ix_i^p}} }{ \big( \frac{\sum_i w_ix_i^p}{\sum_i w_i} \big) } \Bigg) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial J(p,x_1, .. , x_k)}{\partial p} \ge 0 &\Leftrightarrow \prod_i (x_i^p)^{w_ix_i^p} \geq \Big( \frac{\sum_i w_ix_i^p}{\sum_i w_i} \Big)^{\sum_i w_ix_i^p}
\end{align*}
Put $x_i^p = t_i$ to get the original inequality.

But how do I show the original inequality?

**ALITER** An alternate formulation of the same inequality is:
$$GM(f(x_1), ... f(x_n)) \ge f(AM) $$
where $f(x) = x^x$, and $GM$ and $WM$ are the weighted geometric and arithmetic means resp. I don't know if this helps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you normalize the weights and take $\ln$ from both sides. Then use Jensen's inequality for $f(t) = t\ln t:$
$$\sum_iw_it_i\ln t_i\geq\sum_i w_it_i \ln\sum_iw_it_i$$
and getting rid of the natural log will give you your inequality.